# Java look up at 127.0.0.1 fail on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, localhost, vpn

I am working in a VPN (actually I don't know if it affects the situation) on Ubuntu 12.10 and I am running an application in Tomcat 6 that fails to start returning:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Conversion of bind_addr in UDP with original property value "127.0.0.1" failed
at org.jgroups.conf.PropertyHelper.getConvertedValue(PropertyHelper.java:85)
at org.jgroups.stack.Configurator.resolveAndAssignField(Configurator.java:1139)
... 63 more
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: "127.0.0.1"
at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
```

I have pinged "localhost" and 127.0.0.1 and they looks fine. I have disabled IPV6 and /etc/hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1 mybox   localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.1.1   mybox

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

any idea why "java" cannot solve the address?

MORE INFO:

In IntelliJ I run Tomcat using:

> -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djgroups.bind_addr="127.0.0.1" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

The problem looks related to >> -Djgroups.bind_addr="127.0.0.1"

Comment: Did you try "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: yes in that case it says that "localhost" is not found

Comment: I would try to use the FQDN instead. (localhost.localdomain)

Comment: with localhost.localdomain same problem

Comment: Your `/etc/hosts/` look fine and should resolve 127.0.0.1 and localhost just fine. Can you share the code fragment where the failed lookup happens? Also, some details on the VPN, please: Do you VPN to the machine and execute the java code that fails? Do you ping in the same manner?

Comment: Have you tried to run it as root? Try also to put your eth0 address in case you are working with a VPN

Comment: application uses a database. The database is accessed via VPN on a remote server.  The rest of the application runs locally.

Comment: The quotes are suspicious. Can you post the configuration for JGroups?

Comment: Hi EJP, I have added more details in the question.  JGroups is only set in JAVA_OPTS to run Tomcat in Intellij. No other places in the app. This is the parameter passed: -Djgroups.bind_addr="127.0.0.1"